# a list error while reading from an arff file

Tags: python, list, arff

I am dealing with arff file and I am getting a strange error since according to the documentation data should be a list. See the code:

```
data, meta = arff.loadarff('/home/.../RTG50C2.arff')
u =[]
v = []
for line in data:
     u.append(line[-1])
     v.append(line[:-1])
print(u)
```

if I remove the v, u works, but it doesn't work with v.
What I want to do is to put all the values from data in v except the last one and the last value in u.

This is the error

```
v.append(line[:-1])
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

As I said before if I remove (v.append(line[:-1]) ) it works, means I get the last value in data, but when I add it the error appears.

Comment: Is `type(line)` a list? And check the types of `data`, `meta` if you need to.

Comment: Actually, each line in data is in the form of this example : (1,3,4,1,5, 'class1')
I am trying to put in v [1,3,4,1,5] and in u ['class1']
When I remove v.append(line[:-1]) I get the result of u like : ['class2', 'class2', ['class1', 'class2', 'class2', 'class2', 'class1']. I dont undrestand why the error occurs with v.

Comment: So, that's a tuple?

Comment: Yes, in fact!  It is a tuple that I want to decompose for learning purpose

Comment: Could you add the output of `print(data)`. It is unclear what your data structure is.

Comment: If I print data I get: [(0.730878, 0.410081, 0.207715, 0.332717, 0.967756, 0.006117, 0.963705, 'class1') (.,.,.,.,.., 'class2') (.,.,..,., 'class1) .... ] an example, where the points are some values.

Comment: And that has a `)]` at the end? Or is there more?

Comment: It is closed by )] at the end yes

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to solve your problem.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.